# Hapi Fhir DomainResource, What URL do you use?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

http://hapifhir.io/doc_custom_structures.html

this article discusses a DomainResource.

> There are situations however when you might want to create an entirely
>   custom resource type. This feature should be used only if there is no
>   other option, since it means you are creating a resource type that
>   will not be interoperable with other FHIR implementations.

I've implemented the code verbatum.  (I show the classes below (with no "guts" just for brevity) (full code at the url))

```
/**
 * This is an example of a custom resource that also uses a custom
 * datatype.
 * 
 * Note that we are extensing DomainResource for an STU3
 * resource. For DSTU2 it would be BaseResource. 
 */
@ResourceDef(name = "CustomResource", profile = "http://hl7.org/fhir/profiles/custom-resource")
public class CustomResource extends DomainResource {
}
```

and

```
/**
 * This is an example of a custom datatype. 
 * 
 * This is an STU3 example so it extends Type and implements ICompositeType. For
 * DSTU2 it would extend BaseIdentifiableElement and implement ICompositeDatatype.
 */
@DatatypeDef(name="CustomDatatype")
public class CustomDatatype extends Type implements ICompositeType {
}
```

And I've "registered it" in my code base:

```
        if (null != this.fhirContext)
        {
            this.fhirContext.registerCustomType(CustomResource.class);
            this.fhirContext.registerCustomType(CustomDatatype.class);
        }
```

(~trying to follow the instructions from the URL above)

```
// Create a context. Note that we declare the custom types we'll be using
// on the context before actually using them
FhirContext ctx = FhirContext.forDstu3();
ctx.registerCustomType(CustomResource.class);
ctx.registerCustomType(CustomDatatype.class);

// Now let's create an instance of our custom resource type
// and populate it with some data
CustomResource res = new CustomResource();

// Add some values, including our custom datatype
DateType value0 = new DateType("2015-01-01");
res.getTelevision().add(value0);

CustomDatatype value1 = new CustomDatatype();
value1.setDate(new DateTimeType(new Date()));
value1.setKittens(new StringType("FOO"));
res.getTelevision().add(value1);

res.setDogs(new StringType("Some Dogs"));

// Now let's serialize our instance
String output = ctx.newXmlParser().setPrettyPrint(true).encodeResourceToString(res);
System.out.println(output);
```

But that looks like a console-app usage of two objects...not how to wire it into the fhir-server.

I've been trying for 3 hours now to figure out what URL to use.

some things I've tried:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/fhir/CustomResource

http://127.0.0.1:8080/fhir/profiles/custom-resource

http://127.0.0.1:8080/fhir/custom-resource

to no avail...

What is the URL?

And how do I populate the values for it?

Comment: Creating the resource does not create a URL by default. Have you set up and configured a RESTful Server? if so that is where you would add access to your custom resources and types http://hapifhir.io/doc_rest_server.html.

Comment: Yes I gave my fhir server working with default resouces like Patient, etc

Comment: fhirContext is "my" code...where I register the items....thus why I think a URL should work

Comment: To register the resource to the REST server you need to create ResourceProvider classes for your custom resource and register that ResourceProvider to the server as outlined in initial link i provided, if you are using the sample JPA server this work has been done for the default resources as outlined here http://hapifhir.io/doc_jpa.html but you will still need to add for your own custom resource.

Comment: Thank you Daniels.  Now I "get it".  I still need to create an IResourceProvider for the new custom resource...and add some methods there.  So this was a "duh" moment.  I wish the documentation just added that little bit.  Sometimes you're so far in the trees, can't see the forest.  I'll post my basic working example soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.

So the CustomResource still needs its own IResourceProvider. (thanks to daniels in the comments of the original question)

Here is a basic working example.

You'll do everything I listed in the original question AND you'll make and register an IResourceProvider for the new customresource.

new IResourceProvider

```
package mystuff.resourceproviders;

import org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.DateType;
import org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.IdType;
import ca.uhn.fhir.rest.annotation.IdParam;
import ca.uhn.fhir.rest.annotation.Read;
import ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.IResourceProvider;
import mystuff.CustomDatatype;
import mystuff.CustomResource;
import org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.DateTimeType;
import org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.StringType;
import org.hl7.fhir.instance.model.api.IBaseResource;

import java.util.Date;

public class CustomResourceProvider implements IResourceProvider {


    @Override
    public Class<? extends IBaseResource> getResourceType() {
        return CustomResource.class;
    }


    /* the IdType (datatype) will be different based on STU2 or STU3.  STU3 version below */
    @Read()
    public CustomResource getResourceById(@IdParam IdType theId) {
        // Now let's create an instance of our custom resource type
        // and populate it with some data
        CustomResource res = new CustomResource();
        res.setId(theId);

        // Add some values, including our custom datatype
        DateType value0 = new DateType("2015-01-01");
        res.getTelevision().add(value0);

        CustomDatatype value1 = new CustomDatatype();
        value1.setDate(new DateTimeType(new Date()));
        value1.setKittens(new StringType("FOO"));
        res.getTelevision().add(value1);

        res.setDogs(new StringType("Some Dogs"));
        return res;
    }
}
```

then you'll register this  (as documented here):

http://hapifhir.io/doc_rest_server.html#_toc_create_a_server

instead of this:

```
   @Override
   protected void initialize() throws ServletException {
      /*
       * The servlet defines any number of resource providers, and
       * configures itself to use them by calling
       * setResourceProviders()
       */
      List<IResourceProvider> resourceProviders = new ArrayList<IResourceProvider>();
      resourceProviders.add(new RestfulPatientResourceProvider());
      resourceProviders.add(new RestfulObservationResourceProvider());
      setResourceProviders(resourceProviders);
   }
```

you'll have something like this

```
   @Override
   protected void initialize() throws ServletException {
      /*
       * The servlet defines any number of resource providers, and
       * configures itself to use them by calling
       * setResourceProviders()
       */
      List<IResourceProvider> resourceProviders = new ArrayList<IResourceProvider>();
      resourceProviders.add(new CustomResourceProvider());
      setResourceProviders(resourceProviders);
   }
```

URL for testing this (most probable local development url that is)

http://127.0.0.1:8080/fhir/CustomResource/12345

and you'll get back this JSON response.

```
{
    "resourceType": "CustomResource",
    "id": "12345",
    "meta": {
        "profile": [
            "http://hl7.org/fhir/profiles/custom-resource"
        ]
    },
    "televisionDate": [
        "2015-01-01"
    ],
    "televisionCustomDatatype": [
        {
            "date": "2019-01-14T11:49:44-05:00",
            "kittens": "FOO"
        }
    ],
    "dogs": "Some Dogs"
}
```